# TDS FDW Adaptive Server connection failing, But message is "Success"

Tags: tds, postgres-fdw

I was able to build the TDS_FDW and bring the extension into Postgresql 10. However, I'm getting the unusual message that it fails with a message of "Success".

```
ERROR: DB-Library error: DB #: 20002, DB Msg: Adaptive Server connection failed (secsql1.secdev.local:1433), OS #: 0, OS Msg: Success, Level: 9
```

SQL state: HV00L

The code generating the error is:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tds_fdw;

-- DROP SERVER mssql_acudb_server;
CREATE SERVER mssql_acudb_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER tds_fdw
    OPTIONS (servername 'wwww', port '1433', database 'AcuDB');

ALTER SERVER mssql_acudb_server
    OPTIONS (ADD msg_handler 'notice');

-- DROP USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER mssql_acudb_server;
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
    SERVER mssql_acudb_server
    OPTIONS (username 'xxxx\yyyy', password 'zzzz');

-- DROP FOREIGN TABLE acudb_project;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE acudb_project (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    path_prefix TEXT NOT NULL,
    "type" TEXT NOT NULL,
    sec_active_size BIGINT NULL
)
SERVER mssql_acudb_server 
    OPTIONS (query 'SELECT [id],[name],[path_prefix],[type],[sec_active_size] 
    FROM [projects]');

SELECT * FROM acudb_project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this issue by specifying the version of freeTDS in the "CREATE SERVER" statement:

```
-- DROP SERVER mssql_acudb_server;
CREATE SERVER mssql_acudb_server
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER tds_fdw
    OPTIONS (servername 'www', port '1433', database 'AcuDB', tds_version '7.1');
```